# How can i get product details at order confirmation page in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I have created custom module to send curl request.In this i get shipping address of current user but i want to get product details as well in order confirmation page. How can i do this?

Here Is my Code:

```
  public function hookOrderConfirmation($params)
  {
    **Here i want to print product details**
    echo $this->context->customer->firstname ."<br/>";
    echo $this->context->customer->lastname ."<br/>";
    echo $this->context->customer->email ."<br/>";
    die("GET ALL DETAILS.");

    //set POST variables
    $url = 'http://localhost/wrd-folder/web-service/';
    $fields = array(
                'first_name' => urlencode("Testing1"),
                'last_name' => urlencode("Testing2"),
                'username' => urlencode("Testing1"),
                'email' => urlencode("testing@gmail.com"),
                'membership_id' => urlencode("676"),
                'password' => urlencode("12345678"),
                'password2' => urlencode("12345678")
            );

    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    //Lets display our template file.
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'sentcurl.tpl');

  } // End of hookOrderConfirmation
```

Answer (score 1):

In a few lines you can acomplish this task. You have 2 options:

1. Get an products array and their price

   ```
   $order = $params['objOrder'];
   // array with products with price, quantity (with taxes and without)
   $products = $order->getProducts();
   ```
2. Get a more detailed array with products:

   ```
   $order = $params['objOrder'];
   $products_with_details = $order->getProductsDetail();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can get like:

```
$order          =   new Order($id_order);
$products       =   $order->getProducts();

foreach($products as $product):
..
```

$product has every param that you need.